# Prune left child. General tree C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree

I'm trying to create a datatype "GeneralTree"

these are my attributes:

```
template <class T>
class GeneralTree
{
   private:
       struct Node 
       {
           T tag;   //tag

           Node *leftchild; //left child 
           Node *rightbrother;  //right brother
           Node *father; //father
       };

       struct Node *root;

    public:
        ......
};
```

this is a general tree (not binary tree).

I'm trying to program the following function:

`void PruneLeftChild(Node n, GeneralTree<T>& dest)`

`n` is the node that I want to prune the tree and 
`dest` is a General Tree where I want to save `n`

this is my code:

```
 void PruneLeftChild(Node n, GeneralTree<T>& dest)
 {
     assert(n!=0);
     destroy(dest.root);
     dest.root = n->left;

     if(dest.root != 0)
     {
         dest.root->father = 0;
         n->left = 0;
     }
 }
```

`destroy(...)` destroy a general tree

I think that my code only it works with a binary tree.

How do I can prune left  child on a general tree?

Comment: How, if at all, are `Node`, `node` and `nodo` related? Is `root` a member variable or a member function? You declare it as the former, but use it as if it's the latter; `dest.root()`

Comment: so... many... empty... lines...

Comment: How can it not be a binary tree if it has only 2 children? Wouldn't you need a child list for general trees?

Comment: @StefanHaustein `right` is not a pointer to a child, but to a sibling, apparently. That's what the comment "right brother" suggests. The variable name is misleading. It's a reasonable way to represent general trees: each node contains a pointer to its first child, and to its sibling. Children are stored in a linked list, in effect.

Comment: @StefanHaustein The node that points to the right is the brother 's left child

Comment: Interesting. What's tag for brothers? Duplicated? Or undefined? Can't be nullptr as it is not a pointer, right?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry. `Node`,`node` and `nodo` is the same. `root` is a member variable. forgive Me. I am a newbie

Comment: @StefanHaustein I do not understand your question exactly. `root` has a `leftchild`. `leftchild` has a `rightbrother`.Finally `rightbrother` points to `father`.

Comment: Brothers basically represent the same node, right? But they all have a "tag" member...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution

```
void PruneLeftChild(Node n, GeneralTree<T>& dest)
{
    assert(n!=0);
    destroy(dest.root);
    dest.root = n->left;

    if(dest.root != 0)
    {
        if(n->leftchild->rightbrother != 0) //if there rightbrother, becomes leftchild  
        {
           n->leftchild = dest.root->rightbrother;
           dest.root->rightbrother = 0;
        }
        else    //if no rightbrother, it just prune
           n->leftchild = 0;

        dest.root->father = 0;
    }
}
```